# Selenium finding hidden element

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I'm having difficulty accessing a dropdown menu in [www.meridiancu.ca](https://www.meridiancu.ca/). It's the one under "Select Banking Type" on the right side of the homepage. Once I run my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains, keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.meridiancu.ca")

bank_type = driver.find_element_by_id('SelectAccount')
bank_type.click()
```

I get the following output, and I'm not sure how I can find this "hidden" element.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12015/devtools/browser/6f5fba77-4c41-49b9-93a3-64a8363cd35b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Imad\Documents\Programming\Python\dropdown select.py", line 14, in <module>
    bank_type.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code for working with select tag:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui


ui.Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sign-in-panel.sign-in-banner #SelectAccount")).select_by_visible_text("Small Business Banking")
```

Result: The "Small Business Banking" option should be selected from the dropdown.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ratmir! This actually helps a lot. I'll be using this and the answer by Richard as reference for future issues.

Comment: @ImadKalboneh, if it was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I'm new to using my account on this, but it's done now :) All the best

Comment: @ImadKalboneh, ok, check a tick near my answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're encountering is that your selector is finding 2 elements that match.  The first element that matches is hidden.  The hidden element is displayed when the page is viewed by a mobile browser.

I did some investigating, and found that the following CSS selector will find the element you are looking for.

```
bank_type = find_element_by_css_selector('.show-for-large select#SelectAccount.banking-target')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Richard! It actually did help a lot! I knew that option existed but never knew how to actually use it. I'll be using this and the answer by Ratmir Asanov for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the iteration over all options in the drop down, using the following code snippet.

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('SelectAccount')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Personal Banking':
        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
        break
```

Comment: I tried that before and unfortunately, that's lead me to the same error. I got it now though, thanks :)